# PyQt5 QTableWidget showing only first line and column

Tags: python-3.x, qtablewidget, pyqt5, qtablewidgetitem

I have a `QTableWidget` populated with a list of lists. Each inner list have eight elements and my table have a ninth control column calculated after the others are loaded.
I can read and print to console the content of any cell of the table like `print(self.tAccounts.item(52,3).text())`, so I think there is no problem with the data, but the table shows only the cell's content for the first line and column in the table, leaving the others bank.
I should be making a mistake in some place, but I can't see.

Using PyQt 5 and Python 3.

The constructor

```
class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)

        self.accounts = [] # The source is created in the constructor\
                           # and populate in other member function
        self.tAccounts = QTableWidget(0,9)
        self.tAccounts.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tAccounts.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])
        self.tAccounts.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tAccounts.verticalHeader().hide()
```

The member function:

```
def loadDay(self):
    for row, account in enumerate(self.accounts):
        self.tAccounts.insertRow(row)
        for col in range(8):
            self.tAccounts.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(str(accounts[col])))
            self.tAccounts.item(row,col).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.tAccounts.setItem(row, 8, QTableWidgetItem('')) # defined for further use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it.

The problem is in enabling the sorting in the constructor. Seems the default sorting is Z-A. Changing the sort to A-Z by clicking in the header of the empty table solves the bug but the best solution is to move the line `self.tAccounts.setSortingEnabled(True)` to the end of the `loadDay` function. Seems to be a clash between the ever changing row number because of enabled sorting and the updating algorithm of `QTableWidget`